# got UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT error on nodejs while calling same api 5000 times

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios

I am facing  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT issue.

What I will do is like:

```
      const ops = [];
      const length = 5000;
      for (let x = 0; x < length; x++) {
        let op = axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
        ops.push(op.data);
      }

      let res = await axios.all(ops);
      //console.log(res);
```

By this few response return and then getting the error i.e

```
(node:7936) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.28.17.40:443
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)
(node:7936) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 7856)
```

I don't have any clue that from where i got this isse and why. 
I also use NPM fetch module but got same error.
Any Help is really appreciated..

Comment: well you are calling the API _simultaneously_ 5000 times. You are making 5000 concurrent requests, so you are killing the server and it's rejecting your requests. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

Your requests are timing out because you are flooding the server with too many requests. You should split your many requests into smaller batches, and await those.

Here is how it would work with the `fetch` API:

```js
async function getall() {
    const ops = [];
    const length = 50; // reduced for snippet reasons ... :)
    const batchsize = 10;
    for (let x = 0; x < length; x+=batchsize) {
        const batch = [];
        for (let y = x; y < length && y < x + batchsize; y++) {
            const req = fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
                             .then((resp) => resp.json());
            batch.push(req);
        }
        // Wait for this batch to be completed before launching the next batch:
        ops.push(...await Promise.all(batch));
    }
    return ops;
}

getall().then((res) => console.log(res));
```

Comment: it breaks in case of data length is 55, at there our loop run 60 times insttead of 55 times.